# Comparing meta data between two sandboxes. Easiest Way

Tags: metadata

We want to compare two sandboxes with the confiugration,apex classes and VF pages,Triggers etc.
Is there any easy way to doing so, i know there is tool Dream Factory Snapshot but this is paid. Is there any way we can do that.

Another possible way come up in my mind,but this seems to be not possible?
If We take out of force.com Eclipse checkout of Sandbox1 and Sandbox2.
Can we do comparison between them too.

Comment: Use Eclipse. It's free and pretty easy to use for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Please guide me more about this.Like if take checkout of Sandbox 1 and then Sandbox 2. Eclipse seems to have only facility for comparing history between files locally open.What that means is we can do comparision but within sandbox only.It would be Intra sandbox..and we want Inter Sandboxes. Correct me please if i am wrong

Comment: If I get more time later, I will post more details in an answer. You can do folder comparison.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install Eclipse.
2. Pull down both orgs
3. For each org, right click and select `Add/Remove Metadata`.
   Select all components you wish to compare.
4. Refresh from server.
5. Click the `src` folder for the first org you wish to compare.
6. For Windows, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click the other `src` folder.
   For Mac, <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + click the other `src` folder.
7. Right click either selected folder and go to `Compare With` > `Each Other`.

Answer (score 5):

I do it a couple of different ways depending on the environment your working in. For high security environments where you can't use cloud based compare tools I use Eclipse or an Ant script to extract the meta data and then compare the metadata using "Beyond Compare" tool or in my current environment the ant script pulls the meta out daily and pushes it into a git repository and then you can use git comparison tools.

But the easiest by far is using a free cloud tool like Ben Edwards Org compare tool (http://sftoolkit.co/). Just login to both orgs and bingo! a meta comparison for free, there are more commercial tools that also allow you do compare the meta and then create deployments from the comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Francis..Sf toolkit seems to be good but isn't is something business afraid of using, as even Wiki is not avialiable for it. Business would think if they lo-gin with there credentials in that,wouldnot all code will be gone to third party.I may be totally wrong,please advise thanks

Comment: Yes thats why I mentioned the high security environments. If you are using a web-based third party to do the comparison then yes they will have access to your meta data. If this is important to the business then you can't use those services and you will have to do the compare yourself. So I would use Eclipse and download all the meta data from your org. Then use Beyond compare (www.scootersoftware.com) or another comparison tool to compare your meta data. Or if you like Ben Edwards tool it is open source so you could download and implement locally / on your own Heroku account.

Comment: Awesome Francis..Appreciated.

Comment: Just fell over this post again :) In a medium secure environment, I've actually built my own Heroku instance using Ben's open source code on github to do the comparison, only takes a couple of mins. Then I just kill the instance after so I know no data is left behind... halfway house :)

Comment: care to post the github repo? thanks

Comment: Link is https://github.com/benedwards44/